# Minimal polynomial, $A$ on $\vec{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is diagonalizable with characteristic polynomial $(x - \lambda_1)^a(x - \lambda_2)^b$, show that if $\vec{v}$ is a non-zero vector, that the degree of $A$ on $\vec{v}$ is at most $2$.

He had a hint in his question that I didn't follow: *Write $\vec{v}$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors.*  What did he mean by this?

This is what I did:
Since $A$ is diagonalizable, the minimal polynomial, $m(x)$, equals $(x - \lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)$. Also, the minimal polynomial of $A$ on $\vec{v}$, $g(x)$, divides $m(x)$; therefore, the largest degree $g(x)$ can have is $2$.

Am I on the right track? I always get nervous when I ignore the hint and the answer is so simple.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "degree of $A$ on $v$", I'm not sure that's standard

Comment: I think he means the dimension of the subspace spanned by $v,Av,...,A^kv,\ldots$.

Comment: Sorry. To find g(x) such that g(A)v = 0, he finds the v, Av, ..., A^(k-1)v so that they are linearly independent, and then if A^k makes it dependent, he calls k the degree.

Comment: @JohnJ That makes sense.

Comment: So, am I on the right track with my own answer? What does he mean by his hint?

Comment: @JohnJ Yes, I think you might even more directly argue that $(A-\lambda_1 I)(A-\lambda_2I)v = A^2v - (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)Av + \lambda_1 \lambda_2 v = 0$ is a linear dependence

Comment: So my answer is correct? Is that what he meant by his hint?

Comment: @JohnJ I don't think that's what his hint meant. Your way seems fine, though.

Comment: Well, idk what he is doing but our ways seem easier. Thanks for the help Cocopuffs and hardmath!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only are you on the right track, you have in fact solved the problem without needing the hint.

Here is how you could have done it using the hint. For a diagonalisable operator, the whole space is a direct sum of its eigenspaces, so here every vector can be written (uniquely) as $v=v_1+v_2$ where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are either zero or an eigenvector for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, respectively. Now $A^k(v)=\lambda_1^kv_1+\lambda_2^kv_2$ for all $k\in\mathbf N$, which always remains in the at most $2$-dimensional space $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$. This means that $v,A(v),A^2(v)$ are certainly linearly dependent, and the degree of $A$ on $v$ is at most $2$.